# i can not call value.format() ,it give me this error: Method 'format' cannot be called on 'TimeOfDay?' because it is potentially null

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

```dart
defaultTextFormField(
                      controller:  timeControl,
                      type: TextInputType.datetime,
                      validate: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return ('title must not be empty');
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      icon:Icons.watch_later_outlined,
                      label: 'time title',
                      onTap: (){

                        showTimePicker(context: context,
                            initialTime:  TimeOfDay.now()
                        ).then(( value)
                        {
                          print( value.format(context));
                        }
                        );

                      },
```

Answer (score 0):

This topic behind the problem you are facing is called "null safety" in dart. It prevents you from accessing variables that might have no value (null value).

In your case, the variable `value` is of type `TimeOfDay?`, which means it can either be an object of type `TimeOfDay` or `null`.

So if you want to do some operations with this variable, like calling the function `format()` on it, you have to distinguish between the two cases.

**Solution 1:**
`print(value?.format(context))` with the question mark operator. It tells the compiler that the value might be null.

**Solution 2:**
`print(value!.format(context))` with the exclamation mark operator. It tells the compiler that `value` will never be null under any circumstances. This will make the compile error disappear. But if for any reason the variable is detected to be null during runtime, your app will most likely crash.

So in general you might want to be careful in cases like this and do an explicit check beforehand:

```
if (value != null) {
  value!.doSomething();
} else {
  // Fallback case because value is null. 
}
```

Comment: Rather than a cumbersome if/else, consider using the elegant null-aware operator `??`